# can't get django views to filter objects by category (foreignkey attribute)

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-filters

So, I have this class and would like to filter the list of quizzes according to categories (which is a foreignkey). I would like for the view to only display quizzes for each of the categories separately such as 'History', 'Chemistry' and so on.

```
class QuizListView(generic.ListView):
    #model = Quiz
    queryset = Quiz.objects.filter(Category='History')
```

Models:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Titulli"),
        max_length=60, blank=False)

    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("Përshkrimi"),
        blank=True, help_text=_("a description of the quiz"))

    url = models.SlugField(
        max_length=60, blank=False,
        help_text=_("a user friendly url"),
        verbose_name=_("user friendly url"))

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Kategoria"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the category class:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Category"),
        max_length=250, blank=True,
        unique=True, null=True)

    objects = CategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Kategori")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Kategoritë")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

THis is the error on the terminal:

Cannot resolve keyword 'quiz_category' into field. Choices are: answers_at_end, categor
y, category_id, data_postimit, description, draft, exam_paper, fail_text, id, max_questions, pass_mark, question, random_o
rder, single_attempt, sitting, success_text, title, url

tried other ways but can't seem to figure it out, any help highly appreciated

Comment: It is `category` (with lowercase), not `Category`.

Comment: Good catch, that was one of the things I tried and got this:  ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Histori'.

Comment: yes, you need to filter on the `category` field, so `category__category=...`.

Comment: tried that too, here is the error:  Cannot resolve keyword 'category_category' into field. Choices are: answers_at_end, cat
egory, category_id, data_postimit, description, draft, exam_paper, fail_text, id, max_questions, pass_mark, question, rand
om_order, single_attempt, sitting, success_text, title, url

Comment: not `category_category`, with *two* underscores (`__`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`category` refers to a `Category` object, if you want to filter on the value of the `category` field of the related `category` object, you use double underscores (`__`), so:

```
class QuizListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Quiz
    queryset = Quiz.objects.filter(category__category='History')
```